# Migration :: Jboss 6.0 eap toWildfly 10.01+Java 8- java.security.NoSuchProviderException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC

Tags: java-8, wildfly-10

I am getting below error when I deploy ear on wildfly 10.

I have used latest jar(bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar and bcmail-jdk16-1.46.jar) but not worked.

> ```
> 13:46:35,654 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) java.security.NoSuchProviderException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
> 13:46:35,654 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:100)
> 13:46:35,669 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SecretKeyFactory.java:204)
> 13:46:35,669 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at com.generic.util.EncryptionUtils.getKey(EncryptionUtils.java:165)
> 13:46:35,685 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at com.generic.util.EncryptionUtils.initializeDecryptionCipher(EncryptionUtils.java:230)
> 13:46:35,685 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at com.generic.util.EncryptionUtils.isEncrypted(EncryptionUtils.java:93)
> 13:46:35,685 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at com.generic.system.SystemStartup.loadDefaulBSettings(SystemStartup.java:286)
> 13:46:35,685 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at com.generic.system.SystemStartup.startUp(SystemStartup.java:120)
> 13:46:35,685 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at sample.servlets.tartup.init(Startup.java:187)
> 13:46:35,685 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
> 13:46:35,685 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
> 13:46:35,685 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
> 13:46:35,700 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:250)
> 13:46:35,700 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:133)
> 13:46:35,700 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:546)
> 13:46:35,700 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:517)
> 13:46:35,700 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
> 13:46:35,700 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
> 13:46:35,716 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
> 13:46:35,716 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
> 13:46:35,716 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
> 13:46:35,716 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
> 13:46:35,716 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
> 13:46:35,732 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
> 13:46:35,732 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
> 13:46:35,732 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
> 13:46:35,732 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> 13:46:35,732 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> 13:46:35,732 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> 13:46:35,732 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> 13:46:35,732 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> 13:46:35,732 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
> 13:46:35,732 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot verify jar:vfs:/E:/myprj/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/bin/content/myapp.ear/lib/tik
> a-app-1.4.jar!/
> 13:46:35,747 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifySingleJar(JarVerifier.java:446)
> 13:46:35,747 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifyJars(JarVerifier.java:361)
> 13:46:35,747 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verify(JarVerifier.java:289)
> 13:46:35,747 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.verifyProviderJar(JceSecurity.java:159)
> 13:46:35,747 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getVerificationResult(JceSecurity.java:185)
> 13:46:35,747 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76)   at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:97)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There are two workarounds.

1. You create a modul with the libs (bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar,bcmail-jdk16-1.46.jar) and import it in your jboss-deployment-structure.xml
2. You add the jars in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml as resource with the option use-physical-code-source="true" Example:
   `<resource-root path="/lib/bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>`